# How to validate value in response array

Tags: arrays, json, postman

```
{
    "code": "lid5000294001",
    "status": "error",
    "data": {
        "error_msg": "token失效,请重新登录"
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-05-03 17:13:23",
    "traceId": "14121d12f937445b8c12e18c31b11473"
}
```

This is my response body, I want to validate the error msg === 'token失效,请重新登录' in following script

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var env_var = pm.environment.get("token_status");
if (env_var === "active") {
    pm.test(`Status code is 200`, () => {
        pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    })
}
else {
    pm.test(`Status code is 500`, () => {
        //pm.expect(jsonData[2].erro).to.("token失效,请重新登录");
        //pm.response.body.("token失效,请重新登录");
        //pm.response.to.have.("token失效,请重新登录");
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assertion will do:

```js
pm.expect(jsonData.data.error_msg).to.equal('token失效,请重新登录');
```